# Scala development for Android using NetBeans

Tags: android, scala, netbeans

Did anyone use NetBeans for Scala development for Android?
NetBeans has support for Scala (nbScala) and Android (nbAndroid). Did someone manage to use them in combination?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, NetBeans don`t have support for Scala development for Android. The least painful ways to develop are:

- SBT project with [android-plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin); can be converted to Eclipse or Idea projects
- [treeshaker](http://code.google.com/p/treeshaker/) plugin for Eclipse (don't support Scala 2.9)

Comment: I've been able to create a Android project that also supports Scala files. Editing works, compile wirks, intalling on Android emulator works... The only thing that does not work is code completion. I followed http://lamp.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/scala-to-android.html

Comment: I chose the treeshaker plugin. It is the easiest way to create scala-android project. Try it, the code completion works for me.