# Scala on Android using Netbeans (preferably 6.8)

Tags: android, scala, netbeans

I have tried Scala on Android using various suggestions found on the Internet. However, I have never been able to get a "one-click" solution for Netbeans. Eventually I settled for Java + Eclipse. However, the urge to create Scala programs on Android persists.

Has anyone successfully used Netbeans IDE for Scala development for the Android platform? And that too using the IDE's build tools?

Ideally the following features are needed:

- Scala code completion, syntax highlighting, error checking (as in NB-6.8 + Scala 2.8)
- Automatic deployment on Android using one-click
- No messing around with Proguard config
- No messing around with signing of the jars/apks

Please post a step-by-step guide if this is possible, or please link to an external page giving details.

Comment: There was [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054025/scala-development-for-android-using-netbeans) not so long ago. I think nothing has changed from that times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new eclipse plugin? Those are a major improvement from a few month ago. There should be versions for 2.9.1 and (if you need scala 2.8 ) Scala 2.8.2 see www.scala-ide.org

Comment: I have not tried it recently. Will check it out. Does it integrate Scala and Android together?